# jquery autocomplete ul list item highlight when using keyboard up and down arrow

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1003; display: none; width: 415px; top: 267px; left: 882px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"> Holland </a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"> Hungary </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above unordered list coming as list of suggestions when typing in a textbox using JQUERY auto complete feature.

> When I scroll through the list using keyboard up and down arrow the list item is not focused in other words the background of current scrolling item is not highlighted.

I tried having

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:active a:focus a:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but did not work, the background of current scrolling list item is always white.

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,   
.ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
   background: red;
   border: none;
   color:#000;
   border-radius:0;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

The above css from one of the stackoverflow post gave me the solution. Thanks to the original solution giver.

Comment: Maybe this is a little late, but it might be helpful to link to the actual SO post you got this solution from. You could also mark the question as answered if this worked for you.